# Drawing arrowlines between table rows in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have around 10-12 tables in my react webpage, each having around 10 rows. It is basically representing a database schema visually (similar to an entity relationship diagram). I wanted to know of there is a way to connect two rows from different tables which would highlight that a relationship exists between the two columns?

I have tried using SVG arrows for the same but found them a bit cumbersome to use. Unfortunately I cannot share the code here due to privacy issues. Will appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: You might need to use `canvas` to do that illustration.

Comment: I tried to do this with `react-konva` but it's not as easy as I thought https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-currying-z2v4wc?file=/src/App.js